# Android text looks really fuzzy and impoperly drawn

Tags: android, drawtext

When drawing the text to the screen the text itself is getting chopped off and certain characters for example the n looks like an r.  and overall very hard to read.  I have drawn text before and it looked fine.  Was wondering if any one had any incites to why this may be happening.  Here is a link to a screen shot of what it looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried: `Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);`

Comment: I have not. I will try it and see if it helps later tonight.

Comment: Thanks this defiantly improved the way the text looks. marked as the answer

Comment: This is a really nice tip. Text looks much smoother now in my marker clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Your text  size seem to be a problem. Try increasing the height of the TextView your are using, and it should be ok.

If you are using the canvas to draw text, then perhaps try increasing the text/font size.

Comment: I have tried increasing the font size and this does not help. Plus I can not have the font size to be too big.  this is as big as I should make it fro spacing reasons.